# Exibir somente registros maiores a data de dois dias antes hoje

Tags: mysql, regex

Tenho a seguinte Query em MYSQL:

```
SELECT id_tabela,titulo,data_gabarito,left(data_gabarito,10) AS d_gabarito FROM tabela 
WHERE data_gabarito RLIKE('^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}') 
ORDER BY str_to_date(d_gabarito,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC
```

- Ela pega um campo data_gabarito que tem strings com varias datas e formatos e exibe somente as primeiras através da `regex`. (12/02/2019, 11/02/2019, 15/02/2019) pega só a primeira data.
- Ela converte o alias (d_gabarito) para data e ordena pela maior data.

O que eu quero:

Exibir somente registros maiores a data de dois dias antes de hoje. Exemplo: Hoje é 07/02/2019, gostaria de exibir somente os registros com data a partir de dois dias anteriores a data de hoje (now), ou seja, maiores que 05/02/2017.

Explicando mais...hoje é quinta feira (07/02/2019) gostaria de exibir somente os registros que tem datas maiores a 05/02/2019.

O problema é que não dá para usar o ALIAS "AS" no `where` para fazer. d_gabarito>now-2 por exemplo.

Pensei em criar uma `view` para isso...mas talvez alguém enxergue uma solução mais simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque teu WHERE da seguinte forma:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(data_gabarito,10),'%d/%m/%Y'), NOW()) >= -2
```

Comment: o problema que esse data_gabarito é uma string que tem vários formatos. Tem data, tem texto, etc... por isso passo ela antes em uma regex no where pra pegar só a data.

Comment: deu certo coloquei seu where com um AND e mantive minha regex. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo: quero pegar o id e data dos boletos que tem data de hoje e dois dias atrás, logo:

```
select id, data from tb_boleto where data BETWEEN curdate() AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

No select acima utilizo o comando **curdate()** que pega o dia atual, o comando **DATE_SUB** diminui o intervalo de datas, eu passo a data atual e o intervalo de datas que desejo diminuir que é 2. Veja outras funções de MySQL para data neste [link](https://www.w3resource.com/slides/mysql-date-and-time-functions-slides-presentation.php) ou verifique na documentação DO MySQL [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html).

Agora é só aplicar na sua query.

Comment: acontece que minha data não vem de um campo, vem tratada por uma regex e transformada em um alias.

Comment: O seu d_gabarito é o que eu chamaria de data no exemplo que dei, só aplicar a função mostrada com ele.

Comment: dá certo não, como disse esse d_gabarito é um campo tratado por um regex  e que vira um alias. Não dá pra usar alias no WHERE. O mysql não permite.

Comment: O seu d_gabarito é o que eu chamaria de data no exemplo que dei, só aplicar a função mostrada com ele. ```WHERE data_gabarito RLIKE('^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}') AND str_to_date(d_gabarito,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN curdate() AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)```. Dá mesma forma que você transforma ele em data para ordenar, transforma em data e faz o between.

Comment: perfeito. valeu cara.